# OData $batch endpoint not found when hosted in IIS

Tags: iis-7.5, odata

I'm struggling to figure this out - I have an OData V4 service which I have developed using .Net ODataConventionModelBuilder. Everything works fine when running "within visual studio" (i.e. localhost:port/service) but when I publish the service to IIS I can no longer make batch requests.

Example1 : Running under IISExpress while visual studio is running

GET http://localhost:1234/service/SomeResource 
- works fine to access a resource and return JSON response

POST http://localhost:1234/service/$batch 
- works fine to send a batch request (obviously with body data) for multiple GETs

Example2 : Hosting under IIS

GET http://localhost/service/SomeResource 
- works fine to access a resource and return JSON response

POST http://localhost/service/$batch 
- fails with a HTTP 404 Not Found
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/service/$batch'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost/service/$batch'"

so I'm stuck I dont understand why routing is working ok when running under studio/IISExpress and not under proper IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seems this was down to a problem interpreting the url because of the $batch part.

Adding this to web.config solved it ok.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
       <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
       <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```